# How to share properly Entity Framework ContextObject between ViewModels?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm-light

I'm a newbie with WPF/MVVM/Entity Framework and it's a lot of concepts to handle simultaneously. 
I'm creating a WPF app with only one main View, which is splitted in 2 parts : 1 UserControl for a Master view of my data, another userControl for the detailed view. All data is stored in database generated via Entity Framework entity model.

So far I managed to do what I wanted (I use MVVM light) : databinding, commands, eventToCommand... I use following architecture in 1 VS project : 1 folder for Views, 1 for ViewModels, and 1 for Entities definition.

I pass data from master to detail userControl using MVVM Light Messaging,  and when I try to update one entity, I encountered exception telling me that I can't update because I try to update one object linked to an ObjectContext (declared in MasterViewModel) with one object from another one (declared in DetailedViewModel)

**How can I share EF ObjectContext between ViewModels?** I read some stuff about repositories or UnitOfWork but I didn't really manage to see how I could use it in my case.

Subsidiary question : what's the best practice to access entities with EF and a n-tier app? Is the repository the answer? COnsidering the fact that classes already exists, should I have a "Model" folder in my solution architecture?

Comment: did you forget to accept the answer below (which ups your reputation) or were you looking for another explanation? :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the two design patterns you mention.

A Repository is a design pattern that helps you to create a single access point to your data. For example a CustomerRepository which has functions like `GetById(int customerId)`, `Update(Customer customer)`, `Delete(Customer customer)` and `Add(Customer customer)` and, depending on your specific flavor of implementing the pattern, other more specific functions for handling data that involves a customer.

In a regular application you would have a couple of Repositories that will give you access to different kinds of data. In a business function you would then use some of those repositories to build functionality.

Then the UnitOfWork pattern comes around, because this helps you to group a set of related operations. The Unit of Work keeps track of the changes until you save them to the database as a whole. (The ObjectContext in EF is an implementation of the UoW pattern)

In your example showing a master form and then loading and updating the details of one of those items, is a group of related operations that you want to update together.

This means that you should use one UoW for the master and the details view.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) is nice article which shows the basics of how an implementation of the  Repository and UoW patterns could look like when using EF.

[Here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) you can find an explanation of the Repository pattern and [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) of the Unit Of Work (those references are both from Patterns of Enterprise Applications, a really good book if you want to learn more)

Comment: Hello Wouter, Many thanks for your answer. I will try every tracks you gave me and will ask complementary questions if needed.

Thanks again !

Comment: Hello,I implemented repos and UnitOfWork such as [the example kindly given by Wouters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx).

Comment: Also see http://ef4templates.codeplex.com/ which has a t4 generator to generate your repository and all your data models for using in this way from your .edmx file.